# New-IISSite new site not visible in IIS Manager

Tags: powershell, iis

I am creating a new site on my Windows 10 box using Powershell:

```
New-IISSite -Name "mysite.local" -BindingInformation "*:80:mysite.local" -PhysicalPath "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite.local"
```

This works, when I call *Get-IISSite* it lists my new site.

However in *IIS Manager*, the site is not listed and *applicationHost.config* doesn't contain an entry for it. What am I missing?

Comment: pretty sure you need to refresh

Answer (score 2):

When a *Start-IISCommitDelay* command was issued but no corresponding *Stop-IISCommitDelay*, every subsequent modification to IIS config will not be committed to *applicationHost.config*

This will close the open transaction:

```
Stop-IISCommitDelay
```

Comment: This solved my issue the second I saw it, I forgot I had even called the start delay command.